# How do I define a function with a variable and a parameter?

Tags: parametric-functions

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be a parameter.
I would like to define a function
$$ f_{\alpha}(n) := \binom{n}{\alpha n},$$
in order to later get a series expansion

```
Series[Subscript[f, α][n], {n, ∞, 0}]
```

as a function of $\alpha$.

How can I define such a function?

Comment: `f[a_][n_] := Binomial[n, a n]`, and e.g. `f[0.5][3.23]` yields `3.85957`; and then `Series[f[a][n], {n, Infinity, 0}]` returns something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f[α_Integer, n_Integer] := n!/(α!*(n - α)!)
```

Check:

```
f[2, 4]



   (*  6  *)
```

Have fun!